# How to run background process with bash -c

Tags: bash, background-process

I have a command to start background process

`./daemon.sh &`

it works okay but when i try to run it the following way

`bash -i -c "./daemon.sh & ; ./another_daemon.sh &"`

it throws the exception `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;' ``

Is there any way to start background process(es) with `bash -i -c "..."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a `-c` issue.

You need to lose the `;` after the `&`. The shell syntax doesn't accept a semicolon in conjunction with an ampersand.
Either of the following is acceptable

```
bash -i -c "... ; ..."
bash -i -c "... & ..."
```

but 
`bash -i -c "... & ; ..."` is invalid.

Comment: without ampersand, it works. for instance command `bash -i -c "./daemon.sh  ; ./another_daemon.sh "` runs with no issues

Comment: Ampersands and semicolons are both command terminators; using both implies the semicolon terminates an empty command, and `bash`'s syntax doesn't allow empty commands. `./daemon.sh & ./another_daemon &` is sufficient.